# Chaining methods and passing variables

Tags: php, class, oop, chain

Let's say I have this:

```
class "classname"
{

    ....

    public function section($id)
    {
        // variable method name
        $this->section->$id = new stdClass();
        return $this;
    }

    public function subsection()
    {
        // $id is not available here
        $this->section->$id->subsection = array();
        return $this;
    }

    ....

}
```

When I call:

```
$classname->section("test")
    ->subsection();
```

It is not working because $id is not global nor set in the second chainlink. Do I have to pass it manually to ->subsection($id) or is there a more generic/cleaner way to get it there?

What I try to accomplish here is to create an (big) object with multiple sections. In these sections objects and/or array's so there are more (chained) methods involved.

Comment: Where you declare the variable `$id`? Also check that variable holds the access specifier `protected` or `public`.

Comment: it will be better if you post complete code

Comment: Have you defined the class member/variable/field/etc `$section` in your `class Classname`? And if so, what type is it? Does it have a property called `$id` which you can set?

Comment: `$id` parameter is only defined/exists in `section` method. And it is undefined when you call `subsection` method.

Comment: It breaks the Law of Demeter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can act like this way:

```
class Foo
{
    protected $section;
    private $lastUsedId = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->section = new StdClass();
    }

    public function section($id)
    {
        // variable method name
        $this->section->$id = new StdClass();
        $this->lastUsedId = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function subsection()
    {
        // $id is not available here
        $this->section->{$this->lastUsedId}->subsection = array();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

so

```
$obj = (new Foo())
   ->section('one')
   ->subsection()
   ->section('two')
   ->subsection();
```

will produce valid result like

```
object(Foo)#1 (2) {
  ["section":protected]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["one"]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
      ["subsection"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["two"]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
      ["subsection"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["lastUsedId":"Foo":private]=>
  string(3) "two"
}
```

Note, that it isn't a good idea to use chaining like this way - it's difficult to read, and, besides, having method that actually *changes* data, but looks like getter, is confusing.

Comment: Please, _don't be silent when dv_, let me know what's wrong

Comment: it's full of sad people ;-) I did bring some equilibrity as I find your answer fully legit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is not because of chaining methods. It occurs either because you haven't declared the property `$section` or if you've declared it it has no property `$id`.

One possibility would be to define `$section` on the fly in the same way you're doing it with `$id`, i.e.

```
public function section($id) {
    $this->section = new stdClass();
    $this->section->id = new stdClass();
    return $this;
}
```

or

```
class Classname {
    private $section;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->section = new stdClass();
    }

    public function section($id) {
        $this->section->id = new stdClass();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

or

```
class Classname {

    private $section;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->section = new B();
    }

    public function section($id) {
        $this->section->id = new stdClass();
        return $this;
    }
}

class B {

    private $id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using 2 classes to accomplish what you want. Here is an example

```
class Document
{
    private $sections = array();

    public function addSection(Section $section)
    {
        $this->sections[] = $section;
    }

    public function getSections()
    {
        print_r($this->sections);
    }   
}

class Section {

    private $id;

    private $subsection;

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setSubsection()
    {
        $this->subsection = array();

        return $this;
    }   
}

$section1 = new Section;

$section1->setId(1)->setSubsection();

$section2 = new Section;

$section2->setId(2)->setSubsection();

$document = new Document;

$document->addSection($section1);

$document->addSection($section2);

$document->getSections();
```

will output

```
Array ( 

  [0] => Section Object ([id:protected] => 1 [subsection:protected] => Array( )) 

  [1] => Section Object ([id:protected] => 2 [subsection:protected] => Array( )))
```